# php artisan migrate error while creating collection "no such cmd: aggregate"

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4, database-migration

I am using PHP version 5.4.30, MongoDB driver: 1.5.4 and MongoDB Server: 2.0.4
along with Jenssegers package for mongodb and i have create one migration manually that looks like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function($collection)
    {
        $collection->increments('_id');
        $collection->string('name');
        $collection->unique('email');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('posts');
}
```

When i run the comman `php artisan migrate` then i am getting following error where as migration table is created into mongodb database:

```
[MongoResultException]
192.168.0.135:27017: no such cmd: aggregate
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, you are trying to run a command requiring the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) which is only available in MongoDB 2.2 or newer. Your question info mentions using MongoDB 2.0.4.

It's not clear this error is a direct result of the migration example you included, as none of those schema commands appear to require aggregation. Perhaps `artisan` calls a `group()` or `count()`  operation as part of the migrations, and this ends up mapped to an aggregation command.

To resolve this error I would recommend upgrading from MongoDB 2.0.4 to a more recent production version. MongoDB 2.0.4 was released more than two years ago; 2.6.x is currently the latest production release series.